# Error in PHP ranking system

Tags: php

i have a error with my rank system it will not automatically update when the rep gets to the right level. See below for more details.

This is the start of the ranking system. This is where i think the issue is. I can not see the issue myself as it was working and someone messed around and edited a few things. I have tried to find where the problem is multiple times and i have found a few graphical errors but no with the php coding which effected the db or the game.
I know that i am using mysql and that it is no longer supported but i didn't create them i just edit them and i will be slowing updating everything to mysqli soon.

```
    $currank = $fetch->rank;
    $rankp = $fetch->rep;

if ($currank == "New Generation"){
    $max = "75000";
    $old="0";

}elseif ($currank == "Boy/Girl Racer"){
    $max = '200000';
    $old="75000";

}elseif ($currank == "Speeder"){
    $max = '500000';
    $old="200000";

}elseif ($currank == "Skilled Racer"){
    $max = '1000000';
    $old = "500000";

}elseif ($currank == "Street Racer"){
    $max = '2500000';
    $old="1000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Respected Racer"){
    $max = '7500000';
    $old="2500000";

            }elseif ($currank == "Amateur Racer"){
    $max = '10000000';
    $old="7500000";

}elseif ($currank == "Pro Racer"){
    $max = '20000000';
    $old="10000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Wanted Racer"){
    $max = '40000000';
    $old="20000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Most Wanted Racer"){
    $max = '60000000';
    $old="40000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Supreme Racer"){
    $max = '80000000';
    $old = "60000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Blacklisted Racer"){
    $max = '100000000';
    $old="80000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Divine Racer"){
    $max = '130000000';
    $old="100000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Notorious Racer"){
    $max = '160000000';
    $old="130000000";

    }elseif ($currank == "Outlaw Racer"){
    $max = '180000000';
    $old="160000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Most Notorious Racer"){
    $max = '200000000';
    $old="180000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Extreme Racer"){
    $max = '250000000';
    $old="200000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Top Class Racer"){
    $max = '300000000';
    $old="250000000";

}elseif ($currank == "Legendary Racer"){
    $max = '3000000000';
    $old="300000000";

}



    $percent = round((($rankp-$old)/($max-$old))*100)

?>

<td align='right'>Rank:&nbsp;</td><td><?php   

if ($fetch->rank == "New Generation"){ 
    echo "New Generation (1)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Boy/Girl Racer"){ 
    echo "Boy/Girl Racer (2)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Speeder"){ 
    echo "Speeder (3)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Skilled Racer"){ 
    echo "Skilled Racer (4)";

    }elseif ($fetch->rank == "Street Racer"){ 
    echo "Street Racer (5)";

    }elseif ($fetch->rank == "Respected Racer"){ 
    echo "Respected Racer (6)";        

    }elseif ($fetch->rank == "Amateur Racer"){ 
    echo "Amateur Racer (7)";




}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Pro Racer"){ 
    echo "Pro Racer (8)";


}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Wanted Racer"){ 
    echo "Wanted Racer (9)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Most Wanted Racer"){ 
    echo "Most Wanted Racer (10)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Supreme Racer"){ 
    echo "Supreme Racer (11)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Blacklisted Racer"){ 
    echo "Blacklisted Racer (12)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Divine Racer"){ 
    echo "Divine Racer (13)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Notorious Racer"){ 
    echo "Notorious Racer (14)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Outlaw Racer"){ 
    echo "Outlaw Racer (15)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Most Notorious Racer"){ 
    echo "Most Notorious Racer (16)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Extreme Racer"){ 
    echo "Extreme Racer (17)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Top Class Racer"){
    echo "Top Class Racer (18)";

}elseif ($fetch->rank == "Legendary Racer"){ 
    echo "Legendary Racer (19)";}




?></td>
```

Comment: switch to switch/case leads to much more readable code. and please post only the most relevent section, that's a lot of code for someone to read

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first time posting on this type of site.

Comment: "someone messed around and edited a few things"... This sounds like you don't use form of source code management? A revision control system? Using such thing is absolut standard these days. It is a learning step at the beginning, yes. But you certainly will not want to miss it afterwards once you understood the logic.

Comment: I usually download backups periodically but they got lost.

Comment: Can you be clearer: what do you mean by "will not update"? How can you tell whatever does not update? Does it print the wrong rank - what should it be? How do you know?

Comment: Sorry Robbie, When a user acquires x amount of rep it is supposed to change the rank on the db, which then in turn prints on the screen. When the users has x amount of rep the rank does not change and the % keeps on increasing. (101% etc)

Comment: Since the code is incomplete, it's hard to say, but I would try replacing all the `fetch->rank` in the `if/else`-conditions to `$currank` - it might be an issue with trying to refetch an already fetched result. Since you're not providing anything in the means of actual DB-code, it's hard to say. You should also look at the PHP-logs on the server, and turn on php-errors to see if there are issues in the code (not all issues will show up, hence "look at the logs as well"). Put this code in the beginning of the PHP-file to display errors: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`